# How to call an imported function into another function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function called getConversionRate() I created in a separate file:

```
export function getConversionRate() {
  let usaRate = 0.74;
  if (isEnvironmentBFE()) {
    const catName = "CATERPILLAR FINANCIAL SERVICES CORPORATION";

    // If it contains Cat Financial products, make US rate 1.32.
    if (detailsHtml.dealerId === catName) {
      usaRate = 1.32;
    }
  }
}
```

I've imported getConversionRate() into another file, and I want to import that function inside of another function:

```
//PRICE
  if (
    props.jsonDataProduct.price != null &&
    props.jsonDataProduct.price.text != null
  ) {
    detailsHtml.itemPriceCA = formatPrice(
      props.jsonDataProduct.price.text,
      props.lang
    );
    detailsHtml.itemPriceUS = formatPrice(
      props.jsonDataProduct.price.text,
      props.lang,
      false,
      "US"
    );
  }
```

Here is the original formatPrice() function:

```
export function formatPrice(
  price,
  lang,
  inclCurTxt?: boolean,
  currency?: string
) {
  let formattedPrice = price;

  const usaRate = 0.74;

  if (lang === "fr") {
    //FRENCH
    const currencyText = inclCurTxt ? " CA" : "";
    if (currency != null && currency === "US") {
      //USD
      formattedPrice =
        accounting.formatMoney(Number(price) * usaRate, "", 0, " ") +
        " $" +
        currencyText;
    } else {
      //CAD
      formattedPrice =
        accounting.formatMoney(price, "", 0, " ") + " $" + currencyText;
    }
  } else {
    //ENGLISH
    const currencyText = inclCurTxt ? " USD" : "";
    if (currency != null && currency === "US") {
      //USD
      formattedPrice =
        accounting.formatMoney(Number(price) * usaRate, "$", 0) + currencyText;
    } else {
      //CAD
      formattedPrice = accounting.formatMoney(price, "$", 0) + currencyText;
    }
  }
  return formattedPrice;
}
```

And both itemPriceCA and itemPriceUS would be rendered on a page in React, reflecting the correct price based on getConversionRate():

```
<div className="price-wrap">
   <img
    className="flagimg"
    src={Constants.IMAGES.FLAG_CA}
    alt="CDN $"
     />
    <span className="data_price_cad">{detailsHtml.itemPriceCA}</span>
 </div>

<div className="price-wrap">
   <img
    className="flagimg"
    src={Constants.IMAGES.FLAG_US}
    alt="US $"
    />
    <span className="data_price_usd">{detailsHtml.itemPriceUS}</span>
</div>
```

How do I go about inserting getConversionRate() into formatPrice() succesfully?

Comment: The first function is called `getConversionRate` and it accepts no arguments, but then your second function makes no call to `getConversionRate`. You have to pass arguments to the `getConversionRate` function first and return whatever values you want that function to return. Otherwise, you just `import` the function from the file.

Comment: @ihodonald I'm not sure what arguments I need to pass in. I just need the logic to apply inside of formatPrice. Any idea?

Comment: You haven't said what `formatPrice` does, but you just pass whatever variables you need to `getConversionRate`, receive them inside that function with parameters and `return` whatever value you need from that function.

Comment: as @ihodonald mentioned you did not mention what formatPrice function does. However, I would suggest calling getConversionRate() function inside formatPrice() definition to return the converted price.

Comment: @ihodonald I have added the formatPrice() function as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just import `getConversionRate` in the same file where you are declaring and using `formatPrice`.

Comment: I have. But how do I implement getConversionRate inside formatPrice properly?